# How to get Magit to show popup when launched

Tags: magit

I am getting used to learning Magit and I am having to launch the pop-up every time I use Magit so I was wondering if there is a way to have it do that by default instead of after I hit `C-c C-c`?

I tried looking through the documentation but didn't find anything in there to get the wanted behavior.

Comment: You might try hooking the dispatcher to magit-status-mode, which is invoked with `M-x g`: `(add-hook 'magit-status-mode-hook 'magit-dispatch)` Note: I didn't really play around with this too much...

Comment: I will try that out and update if it works!

Comment: You probably know this, but if you're in the magit status buffer, tapping `?` is a quick way of doing the same thing with a single keystroke.

Comment: I didn't know about `?`, thank you for the info! Also, what you suggested worked! So it you want to open an answer I can mark it as correct! Thank you for the help.

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hitting `?` in the magit-status buffer calls `magit-dispatch` and displays a list of available commands. If you really want, you could hook the dispatcher to `magit-status-mode`, which will call the dispatcher after the status buffer is open: `(add-hook 'magit-status-mode-hook 'magit-dispatch)`

More info from in Emacs: `C-h f magit-status-mode RET`